# Webstorm 7 live edit connection closes upon opening up developer tools in chrome

Tags: html, css, webstorm

I just started using live edit for Webstorm 7 (Windows 7).  It is a really cool tool however I noticed that as soon as I open up the developer tools in chrome to inspect an element the connection closes and I need to restart the debugging session.

My questions are:

1)  Is this expected behavior or a bug?

2)  If it is, how can I configure it to function in conjunction with the developer tools?

As I stated above, this occurs upon opening the developer tools, not attempting to edit js, css or any html.

Comment: **1)** http://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/WI/LiveEdit **2)** http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=129539

Comment: Why would you need to inspect the element in chrome, when clicking on anything in webstorm leads you directly to the area of the web page in question (in chrome)?

Answer (score 2):

The second link in LazyOne's comment shows it's been a reported issue for over a year now.

A decent workaround is to open up a new tab with the same address, and open up developer tools there. Although, you'd still have to switch to the tab and refresh it to update for changes.